# Google Direction api is giving bad response

Tags: rest-api, google-map

From today morning we are receiving bad response from direction api in Salesforce:

Here is the response :

```
// normal response
waypoint_order: Array(23)
0: 3
1: 9
2: 8
3: 10
4: 19
5: 21
6: 22
7: 1
8: 11
9: 14
10: 5
11: 4
12: 18
13: 7
14: 16
15: 13
16: 17
17: 20
18: 2
19: 12
20: 0
21: 6
22: 15
length: 23
```

---

```
// Bad response which is what we are getting:
waypoint_order: Array(23)
0: 4294967295
1: 4294967295
2: 4294967295
3: 4294967295
4: 4294967295
5: 4294967295
6: 4294967295
7: 4294967295
8: 4294967295
9: 4294967295
10: 4294967295
11: 4294967295
12: 4294967295
13: 4294967295
14: 4294967295
15: 4294967295
16: 4294967295
17: 4294967295
18: 4294967295
19: 4294967295
20: 4294967295
21: 4294967295
22: 4294967295
```

Any one have idea of the cause of this type of response?

Comment: A few things... I think you might get more traction if you post this on stackoverflow rather than the SFSE. Having said that, this response doesn't look like what you should get according to the directions api documentation - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#sample-response  please post your request (endpoint, headers, and body), and the  response so we can help.

Comment: It seems to me that you're getting return values of -1 (2^32-1). That may indicate a bug somewhere, but without seeing the response value, it'd be hard to know for sure.

Comment: @sfdcfox - wow.... nice catch